# Django REST Framework use different serializers in APIView

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to use different serializers for POST and PUT.

It seems that the generic API view classes has `get_serializer_class` but not in the `APIView` class, so I should just do the following?

```
class MyView(APIView):
    def post(...):
        serializer = SerializerA(data=request.data)
        ...

    def put(...):
        serializer = SerializerB(data=request.data)
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Before all, beware doing this makes your API inconsistent. In particular because PUT can be used to create new instances.

APIView is one of the most basic view. It calls various DRF parts - throttling, parsers/renderers... - but doesn't deal with the logic part - i.e. serializers, getting the objects and so on.

In the end, you'll need to call the serializers by yourself as you mentioned in your question.